# К связывать клиента с серверов, если оба IP динамические?

Tags: сервер, сеть, клиент-сервер

Нужен какой-то ресурс в интернете со статическим IP, чтобы на него сервер отправлял свой адрес и клиент прописывал этот адрес у себя? Или есть другой способ?

Comment: последний вопрос, про выбор ресурса, по-моему, лучше бы убрать, ведь он явно не укладывается в модель базы знаний.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Хорошо, а способы другие есть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, так или иначе такой ресурс нужен. Но он уже давным давно изобретен - это DNS. Все, что вам нужно - это доменное имя для сервера и инструмент для обновления информации о нем.

Варианта тут два.

Вариант 1. Приобретаете домен, заводите его на сторонние (платные) DNS-серверы. Настраиваете TTL зоны достаточно низким (5 минут). Делаете скрипт, который будет обновлять информацию о IP-адресе сервера. Ну или встраиваете эту функциональность в сервер.

Ну или берете VDS и поднимаете на нем NS-сервер, дальше то же самое (TTL, скрипт).

Этот вариант довольно дорогой - там что применим только если у вас сервер на динамическом IP находится по необходимости, а не от экономии.

Вариант 2. Бесплатные решения DynamicDNS. Гуглите по ключевому слову DynamicDNS - ссылки приводить не буду, ибо не положено.

Как правило, к ним в комплекте идет отдельный клиент - обновлятор адреса.

Как вариант - провайдерский DynamicDNS. Поинтересуйтесь, вдруг доменное имя у сервера уже есть...

---

Варианты выше были для случая, когда сервер - ваш. Если же сервер принадлежит вашему клиенту/пользователю, то передавать ему управление вашим доменом не следует.

В таком случае, для варианта 1 вам нужен будет свой сервер, который будет принимать ip-адреса серверов от клиентов и обновлять DNS, а во втором варианте надо будет предоставить пользователям инструкцию по заведению доменного имени на DynamicDNS-сервисах.

Comment: спасибо, сделал. Использовал анонимный dynamic dns

Comment: А мне вот интересно. Онлайн игры в своих клиентах тоже самое используют?

Comment: @Herrgott нет, там свой механизм, специфичный для онлайн-игр. Те онлайн-игры, в которых бывают динамические IP серверов, корректнее рассматривать как P2P, а не как клиент-серверные.